# Type Theory: solution to paradoxes?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, type-theory

It’s my understanding this causes Russell paradox:

$L = \{x : \lnot( x \in x)\}$

ZFC solution is to restrict comprehension. I also understand that Russel created Type Theory to solve the paradox.

How does type theory solve the above paradox?

I think it has to do with the type of $L$ being different then what is comprehended, so it is not a set in itself.

Comment: In ZF, since $x\in x$ is unsatisfiable, the set of $x$ of rank less than $\alpha$ with $x\notin x$ is just the set of $x$ of rank less than $\alpha$, which is of rank $\alpha$. Type theory does something similar, but what replaces rank bounds varies by the specific version of type theory you're working with. Hopefully someone who can be more specific than that will write a detailed answer.

Comment: See [Russell's Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/#ERP): "Russell’s own response to the paradox came with his aptly named theory of types. Believing that self-application lay at the heart of the paradox, Russell’s basic idea was that we can avoid commitment to the set of all sets that are not members of themselves by arranging all sentences (or, more precisely, all propositional functions) into a hierarchy. It is then possible to refer to all objects for which a given condition (or predicate) holds only if they are all at the same level or of the same “type.”

Comment: In a nutshell, in [R's TT](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#ParaRussTypeTheo) $x \in x$ is not a "well formed" expression. We must have instead $x_i \in x_{i+1}$ because on "object" of type $i$ must belongs to an "object" of type at least $i+1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in TT is this formulated $\in : A \times B \rightarrow 2$ and $A : B$ and $\in x x: 2$?  Now somehow the type system checks the types and because $\in x x$ is not the correct type disregards it?